# Perfect square of the form 12...23..34..45..56..67..78..89

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I am searching form perfect squares of the form : $$1\underbrace{2\dots2}_a\underbrace{3\dots3}_b\underbrace{4\dots4}_c\underbrace{5\dots5}_d\underbrace{6\dots6}_e\underbrace{7\dots7}_f\underbrace{8\dots8}_g9,$$ where $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in (\mathbb{N^*})^6$, and $g\in\mathbb{N}$.

With a systematic search using python and gmpy I could not find a single number with $a+b+c+d+e+f+g<50$ digits. Is there an argument that prevent such perfect squares from existing?

What if we allow numbers of the form :   12...23..34..45..56..67..78..8912...23..34..45..56..67..78..89?

Comment: Is there anything special about these forms?  Squares are very sparse, $\sum \frac 1{n^2}<\infty$...and you are starting with $8$ digit numbers at the very  least.

Comment: And of course, your set is much sparser.  Doing it hastily (so possibly incorrectly) I see that there are $\binom {45+8-1}{8-1}=133784560$ of your numbers with $50$ or fewer digits, and the probability that a randomly selected integer in that range is a square is about $10^{-25}$ so it's hardly surprising that you didn't hit one.

Comment: numbers of this form give a sequence of ones and zeros when multiplied by 9, which i find pleasing. I looked up to 62 digits, but its getting quite slow, as you mentioned, the probabilty of finding a square at random is low. This is why i am looking for a more systematic approach. I would prefer to be able to construct such a number.

Comment: When you multiply a square number by $9$ the product is still a square, so in effect the question is if any square exists that consists only of digits $1$ and $0$, ends in $1$, and gives the correct form when divided by $9$. That makes [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225717) relevant.

Comment: @nickgard Nice ! How can we prove that every number of the above form has this property ?

Comment: @Peter It certainly appears true. Write out a long multiplication to see how the digits interact. Also, the second form with $1\dots9$ repeated produces a $2$ in the "middle", though putting zeroes between the central $9$ and $1$ resolves this I think.

Comment: Taking this a bit further, I think it can be proven that the product after multiplying by $9$ contains exactly $9$ ones, with all the other digits being $0$. The first and second digits are $1$ and the final digit is $1$. The other six $1$s can be anywhere except that the second to last digit is $0$ since no squares end in $11$. Also, no squares end in $79$.

Comment: @LapLap, Such a number if exist must have this form: $1111333^2=1239503689$, for exampl.

Comment: What exactly do the “…”s stand for?

Comment: Well, $g$ is obviously greater than 0 since $79\equiv 3 \mod 4$, thus it is not a perfect square